# Reference apparently changing at runtime in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, reference

Consider the following simple code in C++11, taken from [C++ Primer, 5th Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321714113):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::string;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
string s("Hello World!!!");
for (auto &c : s) // for every char in s (note: c is a reference)
c = toupper(c); // c is a reference, so the assignment changes the char
cout << s << endl;
return 0;
}
```

The code uses a `range for` loop to iterate over every character in a `string` and change it to uppercase, which is pretty straightforward. What puzzles me is that the reference `c` seems to change at runtime. Elsewhere in the book, the authors mention that references, not being objects, cannot change in runtime. Can anyone shed some light into how exactly is this code interpreted by the compiler?

Comment: Range `for` is syntax sugar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right that a reference can't be changed to refer to a different object; it must be initialised to refer to a particular object, and remains an alias for that object for its whole lifetime.

In this case, the reference doesn't change; instead, a new reference is created and destroyed for each iteration of the loop. This range-style loop is defined to be (more-or-less) equivalent to the old-style loop

```
for (auto it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it) {
    auto &c = *it;
    // loop body
}
```

Written like this, it's clear that there's a new reference each time, not a single reference that's (somehow) updated.

Answer (score 1):

For each iteration of `for (auto &c : s)` a new `c` is created, at the end of the iteration `c` goes out of scope.

The following is *roughly equivalent*:

```
for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
{
    auto &c = *(s+i);
    /*
        Do Stuff;
    */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of what's being referenced changes with this code. But in the whole scope in which the reference is defined, i.e. (with braces)

```
for (auto &c : s){ // for every char in s (note: c is a reference)
    c = toupper(c);
}
```

the reference refers to the same and unique variable. With every iteration of the loop, you get a new reference to the next element in `s`.

What you *can't* do with a reference, indeed, is changing what it refers to, i.e.:

```
int i = 10;
int j = 20;
int& h = i;// j now refers to i
h = j; // modifies i, doesn't change what it refers to from i to j
```